# Is $2 \times \mathbf{0} \times 4 \times 5 \times \ldots $ really zero?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Is the following infinite product zero?

$$P_1 = 2 \times \mathbf{0} \times 4 \times 5 \times 6 \times \ldots $$

The reason for doubt is that the following infinite product diverges to infinity.

$$P_2 = 2 \times \mathbf{3} \times 4 \times 5 \times 6 \times \ldots $$

This makes me consider the following:

$$ f(x)= x\cdot e^{1/x} $$

at $x\rightarrow 0$,the factor $x$ is not enough to cause the product to be zero.

Comment: Do you know the definition of an infinite product?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I think so. Please do elaborate.

Comment: It's a limit of a certain sequence. Can you explicitly find that sequence? Once you do that, you can find its limit.

Answer (score 2):

An infinite product is a sequence give by $a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n p_k$ with $p_k$ the $k$-th term of the product. Since for $k \geq 2$ you have $\prod_{k=1}^n p_k = 2 \cdot 0 \cdot \prod_{k=3}^n p_k$ we know that $ a_n = 0$ for all $n \geq 2$ so this sequence converges to $0$ and rapidly.

Comment: In other words $L=\prod_{k=1}^np_k$ means $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^np_k$.

Comment: Indeed. Just as an infinite sum is really the limit of the sequence of partial sums (starting at the first term and going up to the $n$-th), so an infinite product is the limit of the sequence of partial products (formed in the same order as for sums). Plus one.

Comment: @cyclotomicfield what is the $a_n = 0$ you refer to? Also $\prod_{k=3}p_k \rightarrow \infty$ not zero, surely?

Comment: @Tariq The $a_n$ is defined in the question: it's the product of the first $n$ terms of the infinite product. If $n = 1$, then $a_n = a_1 = 2$. If $n = 2$, then $a_n = 2 \times 0 = 0$. If $n = 3$, then $a_n = 2 \times 0 \times 4 = 0$. Then $a_4 = 2 \times 0 \times 4 \times 5 = 0$, etc. Each partial product is $0$, except for $n = 1$. So, the infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k = 0$, even though $\prod_{k=3}^\infty p_k$ diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: @Tariq Note how $\prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k$ is a sensible convergent expression, but we cannot express it as $p_1 \times p_2 \times \prod_{k=3}^\infty p_k$. This is why I don't especially like putting $0$ into infinite products. It would be like sticking $-\infty$ as a term in an infinite sum.

Comment: @Tariq $a_2=0$ in the sequence given as $2 \cdot 0=0$

Comment: @TheoBendit, It reminds me of how there are infinite sums that converge, but do not converge absolutely, so that the sum depends on the order of the terms. The odd terms might all be positive and not have a convergent sum, and the even terms might all be negative and not have a convergent sum, but the series can still converge.

Comment: @Joe It reminded me of that too, but this time we're not failing commutativity, we're failing associativity. When you're failing associativity, you know you messed up!